# An EPP connection error occurred

Tags: parallel-port

I need to connect to a parallel port device which uses EPP mode to communicate. However, I get an error "**An EPP connection error occurred: poll : Interrupted system call**". When I try to debug using gdb or use strace to find what is going wrong I don't this error and I am able to connect to the device. What is going wrong? How can I get this fixed?

[edit] 
I use linux. The device used is a haptics device connected to the parallel port. Opening of the device is done through the initialization routine provided by the haptic device SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed now.

The problem was with the BIOS. We had to ship the motherboard back and got the BIOS updated and it worked fine.